# VBA load data from sharedrive

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to load data from Sharepoint to the worksheet, I am trying:

```
Sub LoadDataFromShareDrive()
    Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim destWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = "myfilepath"
    
    Set srcWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filepath, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    For Each srcWorksheet In srcWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print srcWorksheet.Name
        Set destWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        srcWorksheet.Copy After:=destWorksheet
        destWorksheet.Name = srcWorksheet.Name
    Next srcWorksheet
End Sub
```

But the srcWorksheet.Name gives me the sharedrive workbook's name rather than each sheet name and I cannot load data successfully: `Error:The name is already taken.` Much appreciated for any help!

Comment: What does `srcWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` give you? What if you try iterating by number (i.e. `srcWorkbook.Worksheets(0)` and `srcWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: There might be a sheet with the same name as the workbook, maybe hidden. But your code still won't work - you are trying to copy a sheet and give it the same name as the source sheet, which is not allowed. Try `destWorksheet.Name = srcWorksheet.Name & "_copy"`.